# VBA Code to upload Worksheet to URL with file name from specific cell

Tags: excel, vba, dropbox

Hoping someone can help...I have tried numerous things but all have failed.

I want a vba code that will save my macro enabled worksheet (Tab named "MAR") with the name specified in cell CV7 and URL specified in cell CY1.

URL in CY1:  https://spo.companyname.com/sites/MCoE/PS%20Dropbox/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FMCoE%2FPS%20Dropbox%2FU201%20%2D%20Olympic%20Games%2FParts%20Availability%20Reports%2FSURF%20END%2FMCoE%20%2B3%20%2D%20%2B12&FolderCTID=0x0120005428D9E115EDE145BDF8A5D10A2CBED7&View=%7BBA29F394%2DE412%2D49B8%2D8999%2D689C08597EE7%7D

```
Sub Save() 
    Dim path As String 
    Dim filename As String 
    path = "spo.companyname.com/sites/MCoE/PS%20Dropbox/Forms/…" 
    filename = path & Range("CV7") 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename, FileFormat:=52, CreateBackup:=False 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Can someone please help?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far? Here is a link to help ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and it should include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Sub Save()
Dim path As String
Dim filename As String

path = "https://spo.companyname.com/sites/MCoE/PS%20Dropbox/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2FMCoE%2FPS%20Dropbox%2FU201%20%2D%20Olympic%20Games%2FParts%20Availability%20Reports%2FSURF%20END%2FMCoE%20%2B3%20%2D%20%2B12&FolderCTID=0x0120005428D9E115EDE145BDF8A5D10A2CBED7&View=%7BBA29F394%2DE412%2D49B8%2D8999%2D689C08597EE7%7D"

filename = path & Range("CV7")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename, FileFormat:=52, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub